# Factor states on C*-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Which C$^*$-algebras admit factor states for which the von Neumann algebra it generates in the corresponding GNS representation is a type III$_1$ factor?  For example, do all purely infinite algebras admit such a state?

Even more generally:  what about a type III$_\lambda$ factor for $\lambda\in(0,1]$?

Comment: This is a good question, why the downvote?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By the main result of [this paper of Odile Maréchal](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=430797), which was generalizing [James Glimm's famous paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=124756), the following extreme dichotomy holds. If $A$ is any separable C*-algebra, precisely one of the following statements holds.

1. $A$ is of type I: for every representation $\pi$ of $A$, we have that $\pi(A)''$ is a von Neumann algebra of type I.
2. For every infinite injective factor $M$, there exists a representation $\pi$ of $A$ such that $\pi(A)'' \cong M$.

In particular, every separable C*-algebra that is not of type I, admits states $\omega_\lambda$ such that $\pi_{\omega_\lambda}(A)''$ is the unique injective factor of type III$_\lambda$, with $\lambda \in (0,1]$.

Comment: Very helpful!  Thanks Stefaan!